# SwiftUI How to Edit video in UIImagePickerController?

Tags: video, swiftui, camera, avfoundation

I made a Video record function. and i want to know how to use this bar the edit video before i press **Use Video** button .[image]
like this video .
and below is my code.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isShowCamara = false
    var body: some View {
            Button {
                isShowCamara.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Record and Save Video")
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowCamara) {
            RecordVideoPicker(sourceType: .camera)
            
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct RecordVideoPicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    var sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType = .camera
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<RecordVideoPicker>) -> UIViewController {
        let mediaUI = UIImagePickerController()
        mediaUI.sourceType = sourceType
        mediaUI.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
        mediaUI.allowsEditing = true
        mediaUI.delegate = context.coordinator
        return mediaUI
    }
    final class Coordinator : NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{
        var parent: RecordVideoPicker

        init(_ parent: RecordVideoPicker) {
                self.parent = parent
        }
                func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
                    parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    guard
                      let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaType] as? String,
                      mediaType == (kUTTypeMovie as String),
                      let url = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? URL,
                      UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(url.path)
                      else { return }
                    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(url.path, self, nil
                        ,nil)
                }
        
    }
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
}
```

I wish the flow is record a video and it can edited the video length(user can use the bar above the screen to edit),and press **Use Video** button to save the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To edit videos, you should use `UIVideoEditorController`. You'll need to wrap it in `UIViewControllerRepresentable` as you did for `UIImagePickerController`.

From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uivideoeditorcontroller#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIVideoEditorController):

> Use a video editor [`UIVideoEditorController`] when your intent is to provide an interface for movie editing. While the `UIImagePickerController` class also lets a user trim movies, **its primary roles are choosing saved pictures and movies, and capturing new pictures and movies.**

Comment: ＠Ashley Mills, sorry, i can't find any sample using swiftUI. could you provide some reference?

Comment: You need to wrap it in `UIViewControllerRepresentable` just like you did for `UIImagePickerController`.

Answer (score 0):

The topic solution is I write two function, picker a video to get its URL, another is according to the URL to edit the video and save it.
I try to write a struct(edit video), as below. and it can edit the video and save it, but
I don't know why it save function do twice.

```swift
struct VideoEditor: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    var videoURL: URL
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<VideoEditor>) -> UIVideoEditorController {
        let editor = UIVideoEditorController()
        editor.videoPath = videoURL.path
        editor.delegate = context.coordinator
        return editor
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIVideoEditorController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<VideoEditor>) {

    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    final class Coordinator: NSObject, UIVideoEditorControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {
        var parent: VideoEditor

        init(_ parent: VideoEditor) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        func videoEditorController(_ editor: UIVideoEditorController, didSaveEditedVideoToPath editedVideoPath: String) {
            // Save the edited video to the camera roll
            parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(editedVideoPath)
            UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(editedVideoPath, self, nil
                ,nil)
            
        }
        func videoEditorControllerDidCancel(_ editor: UIVideoEditorController) {

        }
    }
}
```